# If two subsets $S,T\subseteq G$ have sum of cardinalities greater than $|G|$, then $S+T=G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $S$ and $T$ are two subset of a finite group $(G,+)$ so that  $|S|+|T|>|G|$, then

> Prove that $S+T=G$, where $S+T=\{s+t:s\in S ,t\in T\}$

My effort: It is clear that $S+T\subseteq G$ as elements of $S$ and $T$ are elements of $G$ also and $G$ is closed under addition.Also $|S+T|<|S||T|$. Then how to show elements of $G$ also in $S+T$? Does the condition $|S|+|T|>|G|$ say it? I don't understand?

Comment: This is the additive version of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1091365/39599).

Answer (score 1):

The condition $|S| + |T| > |G|$ cannot be dropped if you wish to guarantee that every element of $G$ lies in $S+T$.  Otherwise, you can construct counterexamples.  For instance, set $G$ to be the cyclic group of order two and set $S = T = \{e\}$, then $S+T = \{e\} \ne G$.

In order to show that this condition implies that an arbitrary element lies in $G$, you need to use a counting argument.  I will outline why the identity of $G$ lies in $S+T$.  Otherwise, for each element $s\in S$, you have that $s^{-1}\not\in T$.  Note that each element has a unique inverse, so we have established that there are at least $|S|$ elements in $G \setminus T$.  However, we then infer $|G| = |G \setminus T| + |T| \ge |S|+|T| > |G|$, a contradiction.

Note: You can also view the above argument through the lens of the Pigeonhole Principle (with $|S|+|T|$ pigeons and $|G|$ holes) if you rephrase it properly.

Comment: It is not necessary, consider $S=A_3$ and $T=\{(12),e\}$ as subsets of $G=S_3$, then $S+T=G$ but $|S|+|T|<|G|$.

Comment: ah, my phrasing is off, fixing now