# Let $G$ be finite group of $n$ elements and $S \subseteq G$ such that $|S| > \frac{n}{2}$. Prove that $G = SS$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be finite group of $n$ elements and $S \subseteq G$ such that $|S| > \frac{n}{2}$. Prove that $G = SS$.

I wanted to prove two directions: $G \subseteq SS$ and $SS \subseteq G$. Second is trivial, so, I have to prove $G \subseteq SS$. That means that if $g \in G$ then $g \in SS$ for all $g \in G$. If $g\in S$ then it is satisfied. Now we have to find out what if $g$ is not in $S$. Is $g$ in $SS$? Now I have to somehow use fact that $|S| > \frac{n}{2}$ but I am not sure how.

Comment: Can you show that the identity element is in $SS$?

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091365/if-g-is-a-finite-group-and-g-a-b-then-g-ab), with $A=B=S$.

Answer (score 6):

Take any element $g \in G$ and asume it is not in $SS$:

1. Take any $s \in S$ then $gs^{-1}$ can't be in $S$ or $g = gs^{-1} s$ would be in $SS$.
2. The map $o:G\to G,s \mapsto gs^{-1}$ is bijective so we get that $|o(S)|=|S|>\frac{n}{2}$.

But by 1. we see that  $o(S)\cap S = \emptyset$, this is a contradiction as $o(S)\cup S$ is therefor a disjoint union in $G$ so $|o(S)\cup S|>\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{2}=n$, which is a contradiction to $|G| = n$. So our assumption that $g$ is not in $SS$ is false and $G \subset SS$.

Comment: Can you please explain more precisely second sentence. S is not subgroup it is just subset.

Comment: No subgroup property is used.

Comment: I think another line in your proof would be helpful. Let $g$ be an element not in $S•S$. 1. As you noted, $T=\{gs^{-1}; s \in S\}$ does not intersect $S$. But 2. also as you noted $|T| =|S| > n/2$ and are both subsets of a set of size $n$. So 1. and 2. contradict each other; $S$ and $T$ have too many elements between each other--more than half the number of elements in $G$, to not intersect.